# Insert values into a html select from a database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Good morning, I must insert values in a select in a html file from a database, I can not modify the extention of the file html.
I write this with php and it work, but i must insert this functionality in a existing html file, how i can do that?

```
<?php
$user = "root";
$pass = "root";
$db = "dbname";

$connect = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die("You Fail");
$query ="SELECT * FROM `tableName`";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);?>


<HTML>
   <HEAD>

   </HEAD>
   <BODY>

      <select> 
        <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row1[0];?>"><?php echo $row1[1];?></option>
            <?php endwhile;?>
      </select>


      <select> 
      <option value="<?php echo $row1[0];?>">
      <?php echo $row1[0];?>
      </option>
      </select>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Thats not going to work. `PHP` is a pre-processing language and requires the necessary `.php` extension for the file.

Comment: You can use AJAX for this. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_php.asp

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file in directory and add this code to .htaccess file

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

OR

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem inmporting jQuery, and making a script that recive json format data from the php file and the script transposes the json in a html format, and it append to the corret place in the html file

Answer (score 0):

**Create a php file getdata.php**

```
<?php 
$user = "root";
$pass = "root";
$db = "dbname";

$connect = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die("You Fail");
$query ="SELECT * FROM `tableName`";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   print_r($b_option[]="<option value='".$row1[0]."'>".$row1[1]."</option>");
} ?>
```

**after that give id to your select box add ajax code in your html file**

```
    <html>
   <body>

      <select id="select_data"> 

      </select>
   </body>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"getdata.php",
                    type:"post",
                    success:function(data){
                        $("#select_data").html(data);
                    }
                });
             });
</script>
</html>
```

please make sure that you added jquery.min.js file before ajax code